# Variable containing HTML is not rendering when sent by message notify

Tags: rules, emails, theming

I am trying to send e-mails with message notify and rules, everything is running pretty well, but there's one variable which contains a "HTML code", It describes a table of items that were bought for someone.
I NEED to pass it as a HTML table, but it renders like these on the users E-mail Inbox:

```
<tr>
<td>Peep Toe Colorido (34, Marrom) (415-01612--11163-11184)</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>10990</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Sandália Clássica (34, Nude) (577-02357--11163-11186)</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>19980</td></tr>
```

and the tags which were entered in the message type  and  are rendered right, showing not the markup tags but the table itself.

How can i make the HTML generated by a variable render properly when sent by message notify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [HTML Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module, Which will help you to render HTML in your email notification

> Lets you theme your messages the same way you theme the rest of your website.